# SlideToggle no jQuery não funciona como deve!

Tags: jquery

Estou estudando jQuery e estou usando o `slideToggle` e como a documentação diz, ele deve deslizar para sua posição oposta atual.

Não entendi muito bem isso mas ele só desliza para baixo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('li')
    .hide();

});

$('#btn-menu').click(function(){

    $('li')
    .toggle()
    .slideToggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-menu">MENU</button>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Menu1</li>
  <li>Menu2</li>
  <li>Menu3</li>
  <li>Menu4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Porque você esta utilizando `toggle()` antes, faça apenas `$('li').slideToggle();`

Answer (score 4):

Você esta utilizando dois métodos para ocultar e exibir os elementos.

- Você oculta os elementos `li`:

  ```
  $('li').hide();
  ```
- Depois utiliza o método [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) que irá exibir os elementos novamente, e depois utiliza o método [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) que ocultará os elementos.

  ```
  $('li').toggle().slideToggle();
  ```

O método [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) irá mostrar ou ocultar os elementos imediatamente quando ele é invocado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').hide();
  $('#btn-menu').click(function(){
    $('li').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-menu">MENU</button>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Menu1</li>
  <li>Menu2</li>
  <li>Menu3</li>
  <li>Menu4</li>
</ul>
```

Já o método [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) irá mostrar ou ocultar os elementos utilizando uma animação:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').hide();
  $('#btn-menu').click(function(){
    $('li').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-menu">MENU</button>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Menu1</li>
  <li>Menu2</li>
  <li>Menu3</li>
  <li>Menu4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

A semantica está errada, e o que você quer exibir também, ao invez de você exibir a li, tem que mandar exibir a ul, e também não precisa de dat toogle, e slidToogle o slidToogle é a mesma função que a toogle, só que com efeito de deslizar, deixe ja seu UL com display none direto no css, dai não precisa iniciar o documento com um hide() seu código deveria ficar assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn-menu').click(function(){
    $('#menu').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-menu">MENU</button>
<ul id="menu" style="display:none">
  <li>Menu1</li>
  <li>Menu2</li>
  <li>Menu3</li>
  <li>Menu4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cara, verifiquei as edições da pergunta e o AP estava usando o jQuery corretamente. Será que você não se confundiu porque é um Snippet do Stackoverflow?

Comment: Rapaz, pode ser, vou editar, sou novão aqui